How to get the result from the equal button in my calculator?
I'm new to flutter and i'm trying some projects like this calculator but i have a problem and the problem is that I don't know what to put on the equal button(=) to get the output of my calculator, Thank you to all the people that help me i hope that i learn something new with your answers
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  String formula = "0";

  void addCharacter(String character) {
    setState(() {
      if (formula == "0") {
        formula = character;
      } else {
        formula += character;
      }
    });
  }

  void clearFormula() {
    setState(() {
      formula = "0";
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        Center(
            child: Text(
          formula,
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 32, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        )),
        SizedBox(
          height: 400,
          width: 400,
          child: GridView.count(
            childAspectRatio: 2,
            mainAxisSpacing: 12,
            crossAxisSpacing: 12,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            crossAxisCount: 4,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    addCharacter("(");
                  },
                  child: const Text("(")),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    addCharacter(")");
                  },
                  child: const Text(")")),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    addCharacter("%");
                  },
                  child: const Text("%")),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    clearFormula();
                  },
                  child: const Text("AC")),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    addCharacter("7");
                  },
                  child: const Text("7")),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    addCharacter("8");
                  },
                  child: const Text("8")),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    addCharacter("9");
                  },
                  child: const Text("9")),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    addCharacter("÷");
                  },
                  child: const Text("÷")),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    addCharacter("4");
                  },
                  child: const Text("4")),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    addCharacter("5");
                  },
                  child: const Text("5")),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    addCharacter("6");
                  },
                  child: const Text("6")),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    addCharacter("x");
                  },
                  child: const Text("x")),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    addCharacter("1");
                  },
                  child: const Text("1")),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    addCharacter("2");
                  },
                  child: const Text("2")),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    addCharacter("3");
                  },
                  child: const Text("3")),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    addCharacter("-");
                  },
                  child: const Text("-")),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    addCharacter("0");
                  },
                  child: const Text("0")),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    addCharacter(".");
                  },
                  child: const Text(".")),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
                
              }, child: const Text("=")),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    addCharacter("+");
                  },
                  child: const Text("+")),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


I already tried to put many things but i never have come to get the final result for my calculator i thought i could ask over here.

Seeing as formula is the whole expression to be calculated, you could use the math_expressions library and just set the result as the new formula. Like this:
final result = Parser()
  .parse(formula)
  .evaluate(EvaluationType.REAL, ContextModel());

setState(() => formula = result.toString());

